# Rails on Heroku, how do I populate DB using POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I want to populate data using rake db:seed. I can run the code just fine. However, on the local dev seed.rb file I was using:

```
app.post( URI.parse('/check_ins'), { "email" => "test@email.com"  } )
```

On heroku, that throws an error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `app' for main:Object
```

I also tried using Net::HTTP.post_form but it threw an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `request_uri'
```

Comment: hello, you should post the entire code here. Where is your app variable being initialized?

Comment: app.post() is an odd way to seed your DB. Is there a specific reason you need to do that?

Comment: The reason why I'm doing app.post is because in the check_in#create logic, I check to see if a User already exists in the User table first. If the user with that email address doesn't exist, I do User.create(:email => "theemail") as well as send them a welcome email.

Comment: Pretty much, User.create happens on the first CheckIn.create for that specific email address. User has_many: :check_ins and user can only be created by a check in. Hope that makes sense!